# Redirect page to port 8080 of tomcat for remote vm

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, redirect, httpd.conf

I have a problem configuring a remote virtual machine (with CentOS 5.5). I've installed LAMP, JasperServer and my company application (an industrial manager software), but this is my first remote VM.

The admin give me a static IP and 2 ports were redirected to SSH (11122 -> 22) and HTTP (11180 -> 80).

Now I have a problem to access the Jasper Reports panel from remote because I have to insert port 8080 to the domain and I have 11180 yet.

The solution I hypothesized is to edit `httpd.conf`, insert something to point to `:8080/jasperserver` but the main problem is that I can't have a static route because the company software runs on the "*raw domain*" like: `//remoteip:11180/mysoftware`.

I don't know if I'm being clear. I can't redirect all external requests from port 11180 to the internal port 8080 because my company software couldn't run.

Does anyone have some ideas?

PS: I can't enable anything like a firewall (iptables or something else). If there's another way that's a good solution too (the best is something to disable and enable when I need, like comment/uncomment some lines)

Comment: user254948 understood clearly what i'm asking for. @(yoonix jenny-d andrew-schulman falcon-momot ward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell your software runs on port 8080 but you need it to be accessible from port 11180.
You can redirect port 80 using apache with the following lines:

Redirect all traffic

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8180/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8180/
```

Redirect only a particular url (in this case /jasperserver)

```
ProxyPass /jasperserver http://localhost:8180/jasperserver
ProxyPassReverse /jasperserver http://localhost:8180/jasperserver
```

I tested this with a tomcat server which was not listening to localhost and the requests went through fine, so I would assume this would work fr you.

Comment: I think this is what i'm searching for!! Monday i'll test it! Thank you very much!